# how can I customize and change the background color of spinner in android?

Tags: android

I want to change the background color of spinner and customize spinner. When I used this code in xml android:background="#000000" the color changed but the arrow on the spinner disappears. How can I cuztomize spinner and change the background color without disappearing the arrow?

Comment: Did you try to change the color of the arrow?

Comment: What theme are you using?  Can you post the snippet of XML declaring the spinner?

Answer (score 1):

The arrow is black (or close to it) by default, so it won't show up on a black background. You can change the arrow with the [android:dropDownSelector attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android%3adropDownSelector) in your XML.

Answer (score 0):

The "background" attribute on a spinner refers to a drawable which contains the background color and the arrow.  By specifying a color for the background, there is no longer any arrow.  To fix this you need to provide a new 9 patch drawable with the arrow in it.